# Packery - Adding element by jquery click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, packery

I am intending to create a set of textboxes that can be rearranged. The user is to be allowed to create text boxes and then fill them with text.
As he keeps rearranging them the text gets automatically updated in the textarea.
I am using packery library

```js
// external js: packery.pkgd.js, draggabilly.pkgd.js

$("#add_item").click(function(){
    $("#grid").append("<input type='text' class='grid-item'></input>");
});

var $grid = $('.grid').packery({
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  columnWidth: 100
});

// make all grid-items draggable
$grid.find('.grid-item').each( function( i, gridItem ) {
  var draggie = new Draggabilly( gridItem );
  // bind drag events to Packery
  $grid.packery( 'bindDraggabillyEvents', draggie );
});


// show item order after layout
function orderItems() {
  var itemElems = $grid.packery('getItemElements');
  var res_text = '';
  $( itemElems ).each( function( i, itemElem ) {
    res_text = ' '+$(itemElem).text();
  });
  $('#result_text').text(res_text);
}

$grid.on( 'layoutComplete', orderItems );
$grid.on( 'dragItemPositioned', orderItems );
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; } 

body { font-family: sans-serif; }

/* ---- grid ---- */

.grid {
  background: #DDD;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

/* clear fix */
.grid:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

/* ---- .grid-item ---- */

.grid-item {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #C09;
  border: 2px solid hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.5);
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-item--width2 { width: 200px; }
.grid-item--height2 { height: 200px; }

.grid-item:hover {
  border-color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.5);
  cursor: move;
}

.grid-item.is-dragging,
.grid-item.is-positioning-post-drag {
  background: #C90;
  z-index: 2;
}

.packery-drop-placeholder {
  outline: 3px dashed hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.5);
  outline-offset: -6px;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s;
          transition: transform 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/packery@2.1.1/dist/packery.pkgd.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/draggabilly@2.1.1/dist/draggabilly.pkgd.js"></script>
<h1>Packery - get item elements in order after drag</h1>

<button id="add_item" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all">A button element</button>

<div class="grid">
  <input type="text" class="grid-item"></input>
  <input type="text" class="grid-item"></input>
  <input type="text" class="grid-item"></input>
</div>
<textarea id="result_text" readonly></textarea>
```

However, I can not add boxes at will using the Button

Comment: There is no element with `id="grid"`

Comment: `$(".grid").append("<input type='text' class='grid-item'></input>");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use class `grid` instead :

```
$(".grid").append("<input type='text' class='grid-item'/>");
```

Instead of :

```
$("#grid").append("<input type='text' class='grid-item'></input>");
```

Then you should destroy and reinit the packery after adding new grid-item.

**NOTE :** `input` tag is a sel-closing tag so it should be :

```
<input type='text' class='grid-item'/>
```

Runnable snippet:

```js
// external js: packery.pkgd.js, draggabilly.pkgd.js

$("#add_item").click(function() {
  $(".grid").append("<input type='text' class='grid-item'/>");
  grid.packery('destroy');
  grid = initParckery();
});

function initParckery() {
  var grid = $('.grid').packery({
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    columnWidth: 100
  });

  // make all grid-items draggable
  grid.find('.grid-item').each(function(i, gridItem) {
    var draggie = new Draggabilly(gridItem);
    // bind drag events to Packery
    grid.packery('bindDraggabillyEvents', draggie);
  });

  return grid;
}


// show item order after layout
function orderItems() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var res_text = '';
    var items = grid.packery('getItemElements');
    items.forEach(function(itemElem) {
      res_text += ' ' + $(itemElem).val();
    });
    $('#result_text').val(res_text);
  }, 100)
}

var grid = initParckery();
grid.on('layoutComplete', orderItems);
grid.on('dragItemPositioned', orderItems);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}


/* ---- grid ---- */

.grid {
  background: #DDD;
  max-width: 1200px;
}


/* clear fix */

.grid:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}


/* ---- .grid-item ---- */

.grid-item {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #C09;
  border: 2px solid hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.5);
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-item--width2 {
  width: 200px;
}

.grid-item--height2 {
  height: 200px;
}

.grid-item:hover {
  border-color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.5);
  cursor: move;
}

.grid-item.is-dragging,
.grid-item.is-positioning-post-drag {
  background: #C90;
  z-index: 2;
}

.packery-drop-placeholder {
  outline: 3px dashed hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.5);
  outline-offset: -6px;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s;
  transition: transform 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/packery@2.1.1/dist/packery.pkgd.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/draggabilly@2.1.1/dist/draggabilly.pkgd.js"></script>
<h1>Packery - get item elements in order after drag</h1>

<button id="add_item" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all">A button element</button>

<div class="grid">
  <input type="text" class="grid-item a"></input>
  <input type="text" class="grid-item b"></input>
  <input type="text" class="grid-item c"></input>
</div>
<textarea id="result_text" readonly></textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that. But I see that the textarea is missing

Comment: Yes, I wanted to the text that I type into those boxes to appear in the text area but I keep getting a `Cannot call methods` error

Comment: I am afraid not. It should change whenever i order or reorder the boxes

Comment: Works now. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an element with class `grid`, but in your JS, you are grabbing an element with *id* of `grid`.

For the fix, change your JS from grabbing the `id` to grabbing the `class`:

```
$("#add_item").click(function(){
    $(".grid").append("<input type='text' class='grid-item' />");
});
```